# Angular 2+ Iterate over array of arrays

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

The first screenshot is a console log of the array(messageSplit) I want to display. The second screenshot is how I want the data to look when it's displayed - basically each item of the sub arrays in a td table element.

I have tried the below code, but this gives the dreaded 'Expression has changed after it was checked' error.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of messageSplit[increment()];
     <td>{{item}}</td>
</div>

increment() {
    if (this.counter < this.messages.length) {
    return this.counter++;
}
```

Please can someone explain the right way to go about doing this?

The below code will output as shown in screenshot 3 and is not the desired output as all of the sub arrays are inside a single td element

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messageSplit;">
    <td *ngFor="let item of message">{{item}}</td>
</div>
```

Below is the full code for the particular tr

```
<tr *ngFor="let message of messages" [routerLink]="['/members', 
     messageContainer == 'Outbox' ? message.recipientId : 
     message.senderId]" [queryParams]="{tab:'3'}">
     <div *ngFor="let message of messageSplit"> 
         <td *ngFor="let item of message"> {{item}}></td>
     </div>    

     <td>
         <div *ngIf="messageContainer != 'Outbox'">
            <!-- <img [src]="message.senderPhotoUrl" class="img-circle"> -->
            <strong *ngIf="message.senderId == 1">Boost Promotions</strong>
            <strong *ngIf="message.senderId == 2">Lion</strong>
         </div>
         <div *ngIf="messageContainer == 'Outbox'">
            <strong *ngIf="message.recipientId == 2">Boost 
                Promotions</strong>
            <strong *ngIf="message.recipientId == 1">Lion</strong>
         </div>
         </td>
         <td>
           <small class="text-muted">
            <span class="fa fa-clock-o">{{message.messageSent | timeAgo}} 
            </span>
            <span *ngIf="!message.isRead" class="text-muted text-danger"> 
            (Unread)</span>
            <span *ngIf="message.isRead" class="text-muted text-success"> 
            (Seen)</span>
           </small>
        </td>
     <td>
</tr>
```

[image: messageSplit]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not just use an `*ngFor` inside another `*ngFor`? Like so:

    ```<div *ngFor="let message of messageSplit">
         <td *ngFor="let item of message">{{item}}</td>
    </div>```

Comment: @AmitB. If I do it that way, it displays every sub array in a single td, and repeats for the amount of messages

Comment: The best approach for your case is having the loop on code-behind and populating proper values there and then send object to client side and just show that values. Not sure but probably you need some changes on your object.

Comment: @Hadee thanks, I think I will take this approach if I can't find a solution soon on the client side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem can be solved if you correctly use `<tr>`. I have tried your code with data similar to yours, and to make it works as you expect (your second screenshot), I have written the code like this:

```
  <tr *ngFor="let message of messages; let i = index">
    <td>
      <div *ngFor="let item of messageSplit[i]">{{item}}</div>
    </td>

    <td>
     // your next td (From)
    </td>

    <td>
     // your next td (Received)
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is the code that I have tested: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/txnW3YsxVy8ZssAfOcdr?p=preview)

Comment: I already have a template binding on my tr element but I this makes sense and so I will see if I can refactor

Comment: You can use the row number and make the `td` like this: `<td><div *ngFor="let item of messageSplit[index]">{{item}}</div></td>`. where `index` is a variable that you set to indicate the row number.

Comment: From what I understand, you can't use 'index' in that way as I've already tried: <div *ngFor="let item of messageSplit[index]; let i = index"><td>{{item}}</td></div>

Comment: no I didn't mean by index to be like that. what I meant is if you don't want to change your `tr` then try to keep a counter that indicates your row number and use it. So if you name your counter `count` use it like this:    `<td><div *ngFor="let item of messageSplit[count]">{{item}}</div></td>`. I used index as a name instead of count so this was a little confusing, sorry :)

Comment: Sorry my bad, but what is incrementing the counter? I tried something like this as you can see from the code in my question, and it temporarily works, but calling a method from the html causes errors

Comment: Oh, I see the `increment()` function. Then how do you get the data of the other `<td>` like `Received` and `From`?

Comment: You can see that in the code I added showing my full tr.

Comment: I added a screenshot of what you just suggested. That's almost there, I would only need to make each on a new line

Comment: Can you try to make your code like the: `<tr *ngFor="let message of messages; let i = index" [routerLink]="['/members', 
     messageContainer == 'Outbox' ? message.recipientId : 
     message.senderId]" [queryParams]="{tab:'3'}">
<td>
     <div *ngFor="let item of messageSplit[i]"> 
          {{item}}>
     </div>    
</td>
`

Comment: Is your problem still unsolved? You mark it as answered and then removed it

Answer (score 0):

You could try to iterate it using two *ngFor loops:

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messageSplit;">
    <td *ngFor="let item of message">{{item}}</td>
</div>
```

The first loop will take each array inside of your multidimensional array, and the second one will take each individual element of that inner array.

Comment: Just tried doing this, but it displays every sub array in a single td element and repeats for the amount of messages

Comment: So "item" is an array itself? Could you console.log it?

Comment: Same issue, the only difference is, with this way each element in the sub arrays are displayed inline whereas before they were on a new line

Comment: The first screenshot is a console log of the messages array

Comment: Maybe you want to add a <tr> for each element? Try change the <div> for a <tr> and see what happens

Comment: no luck replacing with tr either. Everything is still inside one td cell

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is that maybe is a three-dimensional array. Try to add another nested *ngFor

Comment: Doens't work because 'item' is not an array and can't be interated over. Thanks anyway for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> ```
>                 <td>{{ message.from }}</td>
>                 <td>{{ message.Received}}</td>  </tr>
> ```